# ARM Template for Importing Azure Key Vault Certificate in Function App

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-function-app

I have a function app which calls another API with a certificate. This certificate (.pfx) file is already present in the key vault. I am using below ARM template to import the certificate to SSL settings of the function app.
Note: the function app gets deployed fine when I remove section "hostNameSslStates". But after adding it, I get -
"Code": "Conflict",
  "Message": "The certificate with thumbprint 'XXXXXXXX' does not match the hostname
'blobcreate-eventgridtrigger-functionapp.azurewebsites.net'."

ARM Template resources section-
` 
"resources": [

```
    //StorageAccount
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_name')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('storageSKU')]",
            "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
            "networkAcls": {
                "bypass": "AzureServices",
                "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                "ipRules": [],
                "defaultAction": "Allow"
            },
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
            "encryption": {
                "services": {
                    "file": {
                        "keyType": "Account",
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "blob": {
                        "keyType": "Account",
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                },
                "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
            },
            "accessTier": "Hot"
        }
    },

    //BlobService
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[variables('blobServiceName')]",
        "dependsOn": ["[variables('storageAccountResourceId')]"],
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('storageSKU')]"//,
           // "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "properties": {
            "cors": {
                "corsRules": []
            },
            "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                "enabled": false
            }
        }
    },

    //function app with server farm  

    //cert store access policies update-
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "name": "testARMTemplateKeyVault",
        "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "sku": {
                "family": "A",
                "name": "standard"
            },
            "tenantId": "c29678d0-eceb-4df2-a225-79cf795a6b64",
            "accessPolicies": [
                {
                    "tenantId": "tenantIdOfSubscription", //obtained from Get-AzTenant
                    "objectId": "objectid of Microsoft Azure App Service", //obtained from Get-AzADServicePrincipal 
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": [
                            "Get",
                            "List",
                            "Update",
                            "Create",
                            "Import",
                            "Delete",
                            "Recover",
                            "Backup",
                            "Restore"
                        ],
                        "secrets": [
                            "Get",
                            "List",
                            "Set",
                            "Delete",
                            "Recover",
                            "Backup",
                            "Restore"
                        ],
                        "certificates": [
                            "Get",
                            "List",
                            "Update",
                            "Create",
                            "Import",
                            "Delete",
                            "Recover",
                            "ManageContacts",
                            "ManageIssuers",
                            "GetIssuers",
                            "ListIssuers",
                            "DeleteIssuers"
                        ],
                        "storage": []
                    }
                }
            ],
            "enabledForDeployment": false,
            "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
            "enableSoftDelete": true
        }

    },

    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "name": "[variables('azurefunction_hostingPlanName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Y1",
            "tier": "Dynamic"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "[variables('azurefunction_hostingPlanName')]",
            "computeMode": "Dynamic"
            }
        },

        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
            "name": "testingcert",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "keyVaultId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', 'testARMTemplateKeyVault')]",
                "keyVaultSecretName": "testingcert",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('azurefunction_hostingPlanName'))]"
            }
        },

        {
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "functionapp",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[variables('azureFunction_serverFarmResourceId')]",
            "[variables('storageAccountResourceId')]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', 'testingcert')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "serverFarmId": "[variables('azureFunction_serverFarmResourceId')]",
            "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                    {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccounts_name'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountResourceId'),variables('storageAccountApiVersion')).keys[0].value)]"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                    "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccounts_name'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountResourceId'),variables('storageAccountApiVersion')).keys[0].value)]"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                    "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                    "value": "~2"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                    "value": "~10"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                    "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('functionApp_applicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                    "value": "dotnet"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES",
                        "value": "required certificate thumprint"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "hostNameSslStates": [
                {
                    "name": "blobcreate-eventgridtrigger-functionapp.azurewebsites.net",//obtained from custom domains flatform features of the function app
                    "sslState": "SniEnabled",
                    "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', 'testingcert')).Thumbprint]",
                    "toUpdate": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add certificates section in template -

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
        "name": "[parameters('CertificateName')]",
        "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/', variables('azurefunction_hostingPlanName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
                "keyVaultId": "[parameters('keyvaultResourceId')]",
                "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('invoiceApiCertificateKeyVaultSecretName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('azurefunction_hostingPlanName'))]"
        }
    }
```

and then add dependsOn for this certificate in the function app-

```
[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', parameters('CertificateName'))]
```

Comment: functionApp depends on certificate and certificate depends on functionApp:'expression is involved in a cycle'

Answer (score 0):

well, the error is quite obvious, you are trying to add a certificate for `blobcreate-eventgridtrigger-functionapp.azurewebsites.net` but the dns name on the certificate doesnt match that, hence the error. that is probably not the right way to add a certificate unless its going to be used for SSL termination

Comment: what would be the right way then? I created a test certificate and mimicked the actual api which needs to be called from the function app.. basically tried to do what is explained in - https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-key-vault-from-azure-functions-certificate-based-authentication/ using arm template