# Is there anyway to import a PFX SSL Certificate file using Bicep or ARM to a Azure Key Vault as a Certificate

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-application-gateway, azure-bicep

I am aware that I can Base64 encode a certificate and then import it as a txt file to an Azure KeyVault as a "Secret" of type "application/x-pkcs12" using Bicep or ARM templates.

However when I try to connect to my Key Vault from Application Gateway to use this certificate it doesn't show up in the dropdown of available certificates. I cannot find anything in the MS documentation to show this is supported?

I would like to do a fully automated deployment using bicep without having to use any Powershell or CLI scripts.

Comment: Looking at the documentation it is not possible, you can only import secrets and keys using ARM/Bicep https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: you could always execute some cli command inside your arm using deployment scripts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template

Comment: Yea I think that's the option I am going to have to go with! Thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 1):

*Thanks for confirming the solution @Josh L. Thank you @Thomas for the valuable insights posting it as an answer in community wiki to beneficial for other community members for the similar issue .*

**Workaround:-**

> Based on the [**MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#permissions):-
>
> > ***We can't do it which will list the certificate in dropdown to import the keyvault certificates, Instead of that we need to import
> > secrets and keys using ARM/Bicep. Also we need to  use [**`cli cmdlts`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template) inside of our arm using deployment scripts.***

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **SO THREAD**| [***Import keyvault vertificate to azure app service using ARM***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045238/arm-template-for-importing-azure-key-vault-certificate-in-function-app).